# Отменить обновление страницы на мобильных браузерах

Tags: javascript, html, opera, mobile-web

В некоторых мобильных браузерах, в частности в Opera Mobile, при свайпе вниз, если при этом скролл в элементе, в котором это событие происходит находится в самом верхнем положении, то происходит обновление страницы. Можно ли как-то это поведение запретить с помощью JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хер его знает где логика, но помогло CSS-свойство на теге `<body>`: `overflow:hidden;`